# How do you get bolding to work in vespa searcher?

Tags: vespa

Just started with Vespa a week ago.

When doing this with vespa and yql, it works perfectly and I'm able to see bolding.
https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/schema-reference.html#bolding

Though I'm unsure on how to go about achieving this with java vespa searcher. I don't see any documentation on how to achieve bolding in this. When I query vespa with the vespa searcher, I'm not getting any bolding.

Thank you for your time!
** Tried these**

- I have tried yql and the regular query, using yql allows the bolding to come through.
- Using the vespa query profile, I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a difference in itself if the query terms come from an YQL statement or a Searcher (the YQL is actually turned into query terms by a Searcher), so something else causes this difference.

To find out what, run both queries with tracelevel=1 and look at the difference between the final queries. If you don't see a difference use a higher trace level.